# different text for every row Jquery Modal/Dialog form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How I can change the text that is in the jdialog box message for each row? 
As you can see, in every row in the column Order Details there is a Show button.
I would like for each row to have different text there.
I tried changing the name values, and I also put inside every td element the code for the button, but it still doesn't work.

The specific code for the text:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Order Details">
  <p class="validateTips">Spicy Sandwitch</p>
  <p class="validateTips">More</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">More Comments</label>
      <p class="validateTips">Sandwitch only lettuce</p>
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget"
```

The full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/djnyquk9/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the content of the dialog changes from record to another

You didn't explain How will you load the custom content? but I'll guide you to how to customize the dialog content per record.

**First:** Create a JS method called openDialog(), this method can take the context of the dialog as a parameter, or it may take just the record ID and load the content via AJAX or something

```
function openDialog(content="", record_id=0)
{
 if(content.length > 0) // if you're passing content as a paramter
    dialog.html(content);
 if(record_id!=0) // if you're passing the record ID as a paramter
 {
    // load content via ajax or something
    dialog.html("loaded content via AJAX for user number "+record_id);
 }
 dialog.dialog("open");
}
```

**Then** call this method in each "Show" button you have

```
<button id="create-user-1" onclick="openDialog('Hello User #1');">New Show</button>
<button id="create-user-2" onclick="openDialog('',2);">New Show</button>
```

**Update** actually your full code is a little bit messy but as you requested, I tried to apply my solution on your fiddle code, here's my working example
https://jsfiddle.net/doaa_magdy_55/qtvw75z6/20/#&togetherjs=jSCLnBoUen

Comment: I added that function in js script . and that attribute in the button but it doesn't work. Please can you give me a running example? in jsfiddle

Comment: @htmlcsde please check the update, I create a jsfiddle working copy

Comment: @htmlcsde, Hello did you checked the fiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

atm the text that appears in there is hardcoded on your html

```
<p class="validateTips">Spicy Sandwitch</p>
```

unless you change it with javascript this text "Spicy sandwitch" will always be the same no matter how much times you create a new one. I didnt really read all your code because its way too big , but you can do something like this to adress each one of your entries individually(atribute them ids)

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Order Details">
  <p id="something1.0" class="validateTips">Spicy Sandwitch</p>
  <p id="something1.5" class="validateTips">More</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label id="something2.0" for="name">More Comments</label>
      <p id="something3.0" class="validateTips">Sandwitch only lettuce</p>
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
```

and then, when you create a new entrance of your row , you can go to each id specifically and decide what is shown

```
$('#something1.0').text('new Spicy sandwitch');
$('#something2.0').text('moreeee');
```

Comment: Where do I insert the line $('#something1.0').text('new Spicy sandwitch'); ? in the html code before the <button ... > ? I tried this but it just show it on html page

Comment: Can you give me a running example in jsfiddle? on the existing html – htmlcsde just now   edit

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your code:

1. Define elements inside the dialog with references to hold your dynamic content

   ```
   <div id="dialog-form" title="Order Details">
        <p class="validateTips field1"></p>
        <p class="validateTips">More</p>
           <form>
               <fieldset>
                   <label for="name">More Comments</label>
                   <p class="validateTips field2"></p>
                   <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
               </fieldset>
           </form>
   </div>
   ```
2. Define the content you want for each row, statically or via AJAX

   ```
    var order1 = {
        field1: 'Spicy Sandwich',
        field2: 'Sandwich Only Lettuce'
    };

    var order2 = {
        field1: 'Epic Pizza',
        field2: 'Pizza Without Pinneaple'
    };

    var orders = [order1, order2];
   ```
3. Edit the code to populate the dialog

   ```
   $(".showDialog").button().on("click", function() {
       var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();
       $('#dialog-form .field1').html(orders[row].field1);
       $('#dialog-form .field2').html(orders[row].field2);
       dialog.dialog("open");
   });
   ```

Comment: can you give me a running example? in jsfiddle? on the existing code I have above

Comment: I compiled and executed after I edited the code with your instructions but I still have a problem.. I want to change the specific lables and paragraphs I have...

Comment: That's because you have code that expects the form to be inside the dialog at the beginning of the script. Check my changes and try again.